# Proving the divergence of a series through a better method

Tags: divergent-series

Can anyone suggest an elegant proof for the divergence of the series: $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {7^{\ln n} } 
$$

I already solved it using the Raabe-Duhamel test, but I would like to see something prettier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $n\geq3$ we have $7^{\ln n}>7$.

Comment: Doesn't this also work for $n > e$ ?

Comment: @dean_mi12 For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ this is the same.

Comment: Oh sorry, obviously, forgot that $n$ is a natural number

Answer (score 9):

Note that $\lim_n 7^{\log n}\neq 0$. (In fact, it is $+\infty$.)

Comment: I am always surprised : the most obvious thing to be checked for the study of a series convergence is almost never checked. ;-)

Comment: Ugh this is so awkward haha

Answer (score 5):

In fact, by using properties of logarithms, the summand is just a power of $n$, namely
$$7^{\ln n}=n^{\ln7}\ .$$
and since the power is greater than or equal to $-1$ (definitely!), the series diverges.